# Get the element inside a div without class and id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a pagination div, where I have an html that I can't configure to add classes or id. I have to work with what I have.

I have a problem that when the page is selected it loses the `<a href="#"> </a>`. Automatically the page numbering is as text: "1" or it could also be "2", I would like to know a way by css or javascript that I could get this element "1" or "2" or "3" ... and customize it.

Here is the code:

```html
<nav class="bs__pagination" aria-label="Paginação">
<i class="icon-seta-esquerda-b icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  "1"
<a href="p0/IZ7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2=CZ6_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK800I3=MKJTMIKw=GNJ=/#Z7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2" title="Link para a página 2" id="pc1617030662888_linkToPage_2">2</a>
<a href="p0/IZ7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2=CZ6_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK800I3=MKJTMIKw=GOJ=/#Z7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2" title="Link para a página 3" id="pc1617030662888_linkToPage_3">3</a>
<a href="p0/IZ7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2=CZ6_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK800I3=MKJTMIKw=GPJ=/#Z7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2" title="Link para a próxima página" id="pc1617030662888_nextPage"><i class="icon-seta-direita-b icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</nav>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `document.querySelector('nav.bs__pagination i')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the only one on the page, you can use the CSS selector `.bs__pagination i` with `querySelector` to select the `i` element immediately before it, and use its `nextSibling` property to get the text node following it, and use its `nodeValue` to get the string (perhaps with `trim()` to remove the whitespace):

```js
console.log(
    document.querySelector(".bs__pagination i")
        .nextSibling
            .nodeValue.trim()
);
```

```html
<nav class="bs__pagination" aria-label="Paginação">
<i class="icon-seta-esquerda-b icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  "1"
<a href="p0/IZ7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2=CZ6_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK800I3=MKJTMIKw=GNJ=/#Z7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2" title="Link para a página 2" id="pc1617030662888_linkToPage_2">2</a>
<a href="p0/IZ7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2=CZ6_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK800I3=MKJTMIKw=GOJ=/#Z7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2" title="Link para a página 3" id="pc1617030662888_linkToPage_3">3</a>
<a href="p0/IZ7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2=CZ6_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK800I3=MKJTMIKw=GPJ=/#Z7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2" title="Link para a próxima página" id="pc1617030662888_nextPage"><i class="icon-seta-direita-b icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: So, I needed to customize this attribute in my theme.css specifically. It would be possible?

Comment: @RomeuFernandesBessa - I don't know what you mean by "customize this attribute," but yes, you can do basically **anything** to the page with [the DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Comment: @RomeuFernandesBessa yes, the selector in `.querySelector` can also be used in your css theme.css,  `.bs__pagination i + * { color: pink }`

Comment: @T.J. Crowder When I say customize, it is to change the color of this element. Is there a way to do this that you did for JS with CSS?

Comment: @freedomn-m Realize that the value "1" is out of <i> so it probably wouldn't work ...

Comment: I see - trying to style the "1" - you can style the `.nav` then "un"-style the `nav>i` and `nav>a`  (by un-style, I mean give them specifically the default style)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the active page is always stored in the only node within the parent to have content within it, then you can use `find()` to retrieve it, and `textContent` to get the text within it. Try this:

```js
let nodes = [...document.querySelector('nav.bs__pagination').childNodes];
let textNode = nodes.find(node => node.nodeType === 3 && node.textContent.trim().length > 0);
let pageNumber = textNode.textContent.trim();
console.log(pageNumber);
```

```html
<nav class="bs__pagination" aria-label="Paginação">
  <i class="icon-seta-esquerda-b icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> "1"
  <a href="p0/IZ7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2=CZ6_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK800I3=MKJTMIKw=GNJ=/#Z7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2" title="Link para a página 2" id="pc1617030662888_linkToPage_2">2</a>
  <a href="p0/IZ7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2=CZ6_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK800I3=MKJTMIKw=GOJ=/#Z7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2" title="Link para a página 3" id="pc1617030662888_linkToPage_3">3</a>
  <a href="p0/IZ7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2=CZ6_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK800I3=MKJTMIKw=GPJ=/#Z7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2" title="Link para a próxima página" id="pc1617030662888_nextPage"><i class="icon-seta-direita-b icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can I stylize this element in css?

Comment: Not directly, as it's a textnode. If you want to apply CSS to it you need to wrap an HTML element around the `"1"` value, such as a `span`, then apply styling to that.